# log4j appender with a file url

Tags: log4j, appender

I have a problem where log4j is not logging to one of my files and i'm not sure why. I have some code that runs scripts, the scripts can add logging which is logged to a file using log4j, I am trying to create an appender that only logs for a particular script.

```
log4j.logger.com.my.class=INFO, JS_LOG
log4j.appender.JS_LOG.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.JS_LOG.Encoding=UTF-8
log4j.appender.JS_LOG.File=${log.outputdir}/js_service.log
log4j.appender.JS_LOG.MaxFileSize=2MB
log4j.appender.JS_LOG.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.JS_LOG.Append=true
log4j.appender.JS_LOG=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.JS_LOG.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
```

the above appender works and i get this in my log file

```
2012-04-18 11:25:52,043 [<MD> Inc Msg Dispatch-1 New] INFO  com.my.class.file:/myfile  - info
```

when the script logs something it logs to a logger of the form
`com.my.class.file:/myfile` this appears in the log using the above config in my log4j.properties file.

if I change the above to:

```
log4j.logger.com.my.class.file:/myfile=INFO, JS_LOG
log4j.appender.JS_LOG.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.JS_LOG.Encoding=UTF-8
log4j.appender.JS_LOG.File=${log.outputdir}/js_service.log
log4j.appender.JS_LOG.MaxFileSize=2MB
log4j.appender.JS_LOG.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.JS_LOG.Append=true
log4j.appender.JS_LOG=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.JS_LOG.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
```

nothing is logged to the file. I would have thought this should work? I retrieve the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem, its something to do with the file: in my log4j.properties I changed the appender to file_ then in my code I do some manipulation to the file url to make it match the appender.